# The role of the series resistors for ESD protection

Tags: esd

[image]

When one needs to protect a transistor or I/O pin of a processor, then a TVS diode can be placed between the connector and the transistor. Also a series resistor (R1) can be placed between the connector and the TVS diode in order to protect the diode. However, is it useful to have a resistor(2) between the diode and the transistor? The circuit is shown above.

If so, what's the function of R2? Also, what's the recommended resistance for R2? Often it is not easy to just increase the resistor value, because it can degrade the signal integrity. Is 47 ohms enough, or should it be also 100 ohms or higher?

Answer (score 5):

The role of R1 and R2 resistors is to limit ESD currents for extra level of ESD protection.

The R1 limits the spike current into TVS diode. When you apply a 15-kV ESD event, the current spike across the TVS will be 15,000/100 = 150 A. A typical TVS diode (like Littlefuse [SP4020](https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diode_arrays/littelfuse_tvs_diode_array_sp4020_datasheet.pdf.pdf), 3.3V breakdown) has the dynamic resistance of about 0.4 Ohms, so the spike will result in about 60 V peak amplitude. This might be damaging to GPIO internals of the connected IC.

All ICs do have internal ring of ESD protection, typically using ["clamping diodes"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/350672/117785), and they do have obvious electrical limits. The second resistor R2 will limit the ESD current spike to 60/100 = 600 mA, and this short pulse is less likely to destroy the GPIO of the IC.

The values of resistors obviously depend on signal bandwidth on that particular GPIO. Pin/package capacitances will degrade the signal, and the values usually are a trade-off between acceptable signal integrity and required level of ESD protection. You might need no resistors at all if your product has properly-designed shielding.

Comment: The ESD gun has a 330Ω discharge resistance (per IEC61000-4-2).  15kV is air discharge.  How much series resistance does the air gap add?

Comment: @NickAlexeev, air gap has infinite resistance, but plasma cord (air breakdown/electron avalanche) is usually considered as having zero resistance.

Comment: I'm curious.  If the plasma cord has zero resistance, then why does the standard have different voltages, say ±8kV contact discharge and ±15kV air discharge?  Why not simply prescribe ±15kV for both contact and air?

Comment: @NickAlexeev,  Air discharge is used to find weak spots in interface shielding, where field distribution hard to predict, and usually requires higher voltage. The discharge usually goes into ground plane, and failures are usually due to ground bounce. The spot contact goes directly into interface circuitry and over a different path, exposing different potential weaknesses.

Answer (score 2):

R2 is normally used to protect the input from the -0.7 volts the clamp diode will allow if the input voltage is negative. R2 reduces the current (+ or -) that can flow from the clamp diode that is out-of-range for that input pin. R2 can be 100 ohms as well, but R1 helps protect the clamp diode from strong voltage spikes by limiting the current it must sink regardless of polarity.

The values of R1 *plus* R2 are only an issue if the data rate is above 50 to 100 MHZ. Combined with the input capacitance of the IC it creates a time-constant. Normally R1 + R2 just increase the rise/fall time of a digital signal.

However use of the resistors and clamp diode implies that the signal is from a distant source, assuming a common ground wire connects any input devices. In a noisy location with long wire runs this design is justified, even if it is a shielded cable. It may help if the IC input had Schmitt trigger inputs to clean up noise.

For a source on the same circuit board or a mounted daughter board *such extra protection is a waste of money and space*. Schmitt trigger inputs will clean up mild noise.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!  I wanted to protect the pins against the ESD generated by human body, when the products(boards) are handled. Then shouldn't I worry about the clamping voltage of -0.7V to 20V?

Comment: An input pin already has a high resistance, then is the resistor actually for an output pin only?

Comment: And yes, I have a I2C bus over a breakout cable with multiple I2C slaves. When I use R1, R2 for the I2C master and all the slave devices, then I'm having 400 ohms between the master and each of the slaves. So I wondered if I really need about 100 ohms for R2. I'm using a I2C repeater, but this resistance could still be a problem.

Comment: You are just fine with 3 resistors and a clamp diode for ESD protection. I2C data rate it too slow to be affected by R1 and R2. If it works don't fix it

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say 2 resistors.

Comment: @Nownuri The whole reason CMOS semiconductors are sensitive to ESD is because the very thin insulating gate oxide that makes the input of a MOSFET high impedance is very easily punched through if the voltage exceeds it's design limits. Being high impedance on its own doesn't mean anything for ESD tolerance.

Comment: @Nownuri An input pin has high IMPEDANCE. High impedance means high frequency currents can and still do flow into the pin until the gate capacitance is charged up. Only afterwards does it block current as and appear as a "high resistance" and block DC current. But even then, high frequency currents can still flow because the capacitor cannot charge to a steady voltage level to block them since high frequency currents are always changing in level by definition.

Comment: @Nownuri Furthermore, this high impedance due to the very thin insulating gate oxide which IS the voltage sensitive part of a MOSFET that we are trying to protect. If a high impedance gate was all that was necessary to protect against ESD, we would never need ESD protection for semiconductor parts. In fact, having it low impedance would protect it better than high. What gets damaged more by a moving train? Open ground (low impedance)? Or a wall? (high impedance)